# Google App Script: Making Fractions Look Right

Tags: google-apps-script, fractions

I'm trying to create a problem generator for my math class. I want fractions to use the format available in google docs when using the equation editor.

But I can't figure out how to use set that format using apps script.

What code do I need to access the equation editor styles?

Answer (score 1):

This Google documentation explains Apps script equation class methods: [Class-equation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/equation). In particular, check `setAttributes()`

Comment: Thanks! But I'm new to app script, and this documentation does not show an example. How can I make an equation a part of that class?